# Dotless breaks on any mixins

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7, dotless

I have broken my LESS stylesheets into several different sheets, mixins, variables, etc.

Variables work throughout my stylesheets but if I try to use a mixin outside of the stylesheet it's defined in I get an error saying that the mixin is undefined.

I'm writing an MVC application using System.Web.Optimization bundling and Umbraco.

Comment: It sounds like the import path to the mixin less file is incorrect or that that mixin isn't in the included file. Ordering of imports shouldn't cause this error.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was the order that's causing it. The paths are correct - this has been tested.